# Windows 10 is selecting everything in the UI endlessly

Tags: windows, debugging, windowserror

Here's a video that shows what's happening.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTAIj.jpg

It's highlighting each UI item one by one over and over.

I tried restarting my computer but it does not fix it. My computer is unusable in this state because it blocks me if I try to select something.

How do i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got something resting on your keyboard and holding down the TAB key.

Comment: omg you're right haha. I didn't realize there was a second keyboard connected to my computer. It was hidden under some stuff which was pressing down on the tab key.